# App-Updater from git repo

Tags: java, swing, git, desktop-application, auto-update

I'd like to make an auto updater for my (Swing based) Java Applications, which automatically downloads the newest version from a git repository and updates itself.

Can you give me some links or explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix & supports auto-update.